# неправильный id модели после firstOrCreate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

у меня есть кусок кода который у модели вызывает метод `firstOrCreate`, срабатывает create, мне возвращается модель с неверным полем `id`.

разобрался, проблема оказалась в методе `boot` класса `AppServiceProvider`, я там добавил слушатель `DB::listen` для сохранения лога sql-запросов в таблицу `logs`, судя по всему слушатель срабатывает моментально после выполнения sql-запроса.

в `firstOrCreate` мне возвращается моя модель, но с последним `id` из таблицы `logs` т.к. внутри laravel он берется из `lastInsertId()`.

вроде бы ошибка логическая, но не понятно как теперь её обойти, без прямой выборки из базы после создания объекта у меня нет его идентификатора. предположим что я хочу сохранять sql-запросы именно в таблицу для удобства выборки и никак иначе, как в этом случае поступить?

Laravel 8.4

Дополнение для конкурса:

В данный момент реализовал следующим образом:

```
public function boot()
{
    $_SERVER['CURRENT_REQUEST'] = md5(json_encode($_SERVER));
    DB::listen(
        function ($query) {
            $_SERVER['QUERY_SAVED'][] = [...];
        }
    );
    register_shutdown_function(function(){
        if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_SAVED'])){
            foreach ($_SERVER['QUERY_SAVED'] as $q){
                Logs::create(...);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Пришлось задействовать глобальную переменную т.к. ничего лучше не придумал. слышал мнения что использование глобальных переменных плохая практика т.к. за ними нет контроля. Приемлемо ли это в данном случае если принять что я сам этот ключ нигде не изменяю?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [другое соединение с БД](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#database-connections) для логирования.

Обсуждение проблемы тут: [Eloquent queries within DB::listen wipes model relation attributes #25768](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25768)